# Make text default selected in dialog inputbox

Tags: terminal, dialog

I'm using dialog for a terminal GUI and I have a inputbox where I would like to have the text `$1` default selected when it is displayed in the GUI. I want to be able to start writing new input directly, withouth having to press the delete-key to delete the current displayed value.

Here is a sample program showing how it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

gui-read-acronym()
{
    dialog \
        --backtitle "BACKTITLE" \
        --title "TITLE" \
        --inputbox "Select acronym" \
        24 80 \
        "$1" \
        3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
}

selected=$( gui-read-acronym "mega18" )
```

How can I make the text "default selected" when its shown in the GUI?

Comment: If you press *control*/U, that erases the text.  dialog won't erase it by itself.

Comment: Ah, nice, `ctrl u` (select+delete-ish) will save me some key strokes.